# How do I toggle multiple list elements with same class?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list with 5 elements of the same class: "navbar_item". With this code I toggle the 'active' status when clicking the item with the class mentioned, but it only toggles the first element of the list. What do I do to toggle all of them?

```
const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
const menuMenu = document.querySelector('.navbar_menu');
const menuItem = document.querySelector('.navbar_item');

const mobileMenu = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
    menuMenu.classList.toggle('active');
    menuItem.classList.toggle('active');
};

menu.addEventListener('click', mobileMenu);
menuItem.addEventListener('click', mobileMenu);
```

Comment: `const menuItem = document.querySelector('.navbar_item');` only selects the first (of any) element matching the selector, or returns null; take a look at the documentation: [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: 1. Use `querySelectorAll`. 2. It will return a _collection_ (a list) of elements, so you won't be able to do `myElements.classList.toggle`. jQuery can, but not vanilla JS. You have to iterate your elements collection with a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `querySelectorAll` to get all elements. This provides a list which you can iterate or loop through to both apply eventListeners and toggle classes.

Something like this

```js
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar_item');

const mobileMenu = () => {
    menuItem.forEach( (item) => {
        item.classList.toggle('active');
  })       
};

menuItem.forEach( (item)=> {
    item.addEventListener('click', mobileMenu)
})
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.navbar_item{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar_menu">
  <div class="navbar_item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="navbar_item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="navbar_item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="navbar_item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="navbar_item">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

because "querySelector" will only get the first element, if you want to get All; please use "querySelectorAll"; you can also to learn Event delegation to get a better way to solove this problem

```
const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
const menuMenu = document.querySelector('.navbar_menu');
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar_item');

const mobileMenu = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
    menuMenu.classList.toggle('active');
};

menu.addEventListener('click', mobileMenu);
for(let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i ++) {
  menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    menuItem[i].classList.toggle('active');
  });
}
```